# How to check cookies in browser are set to httponly

Tags: c#, cookies

I have set cookies to http only. But how can I verify it via browser?. Is there is any way that we can check whether the cookies only accept http?

```
HttpCookie HttpOnlyCookie = new HttpCookie("Code", Code);
HttpOnlyCookie.HttpOnly = true;
Response.Cookies.Add(HttpOnlyCookie);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use your browser dev tools. In Firebug there is a Cookies tab. In Chrome I use '[EditThisCookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg?hl=en)' extension. Both of which show a 'HttpOnly' checkbox to verify the setting.

[image]

Comment: I know there's a reasonable explanation for this.  I can see the httpOnly cookie and its contents in the inspector.  But somehow the Javascript environment within that page is prevented from seeing it.  Isn't there some form of security violation here?    Shouldn't the cookie be hidden and encrypted completely?

Comment: Latest versions of Chrome do not show Server (HTTP) or Secure cookies anymore. It's a security violation. The HTTP cookies should not be available to javascript. It defeats the purpose of having such cookies.

Answer (score 0):

One-click filters of [StorageAce](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/storageace/cpbgcbmddckpmhfbdckeolkkhkjjmplo) will be the easiest way to verify:

Steps to visualize:

1. Install [StorageAce](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/storageace/cpbgcbmddckpmhfbdckeolkkhkjjmplo) chrome extension.
2. Click the storageAce icon on this tab (the tab of current question).
3. Click the "HttpOnly" one-click quick filter.
4. All the filtered cookies are **HttpOnly** and you will see that HttpOnly cell is checked for each of these filtered cookies in the Developer Tools --> Application --> Cookies.

**HttpOnly cookies using StorageAce**
[image]

**HttpOnly cookies using Developer Tools**
[image]

If you need to see **Non-HttpOnly cookies**, then you can switch ON the **Invert Filter Toggle** as below:

[image]