# Cookies won't set in browser but does in postman

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have searched around, but still can't get it to work. I followed [this](https://www.codingdeft.com/posts/react-authentication-mern-node-passport-express-mongo/) blog to set things up.

this is where I send my cookie (server):

```
//after user is has been authenticated
export const logInUser = async (req, res, next) => {
try {
  const token = getToken({ _id: req.user._id, username: req.user.username, email: req.user.email})
  const refreshToken = getRefreshToken({  _id: req.user._id, username: req.user.username, email: req.user.email})
  await User.findOne({ username: req.user.username}).then((user)=>{
      user.refreshToken.push({ refreshToken })
      user.save((error, user) => {
        if (error) {
          res.status(500).json(error)
        } else {
          //sending the cookie
          res.cookie("refreshToken", refreshToken, {httpOnly: true, secure: !dev, signed: true, maxAge: (60 * 60 * 24 * 30) * 1000, sameSite: "none"})
          res.send({ success: true, token,  _id: req.user._id, username: req.user.username, email: req.user.email})
        }
      })
    })
} catch (error) {
  next(error)
    res.status(500).json(error)
    console.log(error)
}
}
```

index.js (server):

```
const corsOptions ={
origin: true, 
credentials:true,
optionSuccessStatus:200
}
app.use(express.json());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(morgan("common"));
app.use(cookieParser(process.env.COOKIE_SECRET))
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(passport.initialize());
```

making the request on the client-side (using next.js):

```
function login(username, password) {
axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/auth/login", {username, password}, {withCredentials: true, credentials: 'include'}).then((res)=>{
  setCurrentUser(res.data)
}).catch((error)=>{
  console.log(error)
})
}
```

[Response in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXtGP.png)

Everything works perfectly in postman

Comment: What response do you get from the server?

Comment: @juliomalves I have added a picture of the response

Comment: Your cookie is httpOnly, you can't see it in javascript. But instead of looking at the XHR result, look at your devtools' network tab and you'll see the Set-Cookie header is there, and look at the application tab and see the cookie is actually set.

Comment: Can't find it in the network or application tab. Even if I set httpOnly to false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this by getting rid of the `sameSite: "none"` attribute on the cookie in this line `res.cookie("refreshToken", refreshToken, {httpOnly: true, secure: !dev, signed: true, maxAge: (60 * 60 * 24 * 30) * 1000, sameSite: "none"})`

Comment: To use `sameSite: "none"` then `secure` must be set to `true`, which in your development environment wasn't the case.

Answer (score 1):

IF you are trying to see the cookie in your browser devtools then check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38604501/16091749.

If what you are trying to do is to access your cookie from your Next app, then you can't do that unless you disable the httpOnly flag, which is not recommended in this case because you are keeping sensitive data in this cookie, so if you disable this flag your cookie will be vulnerable to any malicious script that may be in contact with it. For more info about the cookies check this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies

Comment: I am not trying to access the cookie, I want to include it in subsequent requests, but since the cookie is not set, it doesn't get included.
I have the {withCredentials: true, credentials: 'include'} config on axios

Comment: Are you checking in your backend that the cookie is not included in the next request? Because once the cookie is setted in your browser you don't need to do anything else. They get included automatically in every request. Try to check in your backend if you are receiving the cookie in another request after the one setting the cookie.